# Authenticate Google Composer http call task with IAP protected app

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-iam, google-iap

I have a setup where I have an app engine REST application and a Google composer / airflow DAG that has a task where it is supposed to fetch data from one of the endpoints of the app. The app is protected by IAP. I have added the service account under which Airflow runs to the "IAP-secured Web App User" list, however each time the step executes the response to the http call is the Google Sign-In page. Any idea if any additional step is needed?

The code for my DAG step:

```py
def get_data():
    r = requests.get(url="url-to-my-app-endpoint>")
    print('stuff:')
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)
    return 1

# ...

python_fetch_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_fetch_data',
    python_callable=get_data,
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=True,
    priority_weight=2
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account explains how to extend your DAG code so that it sends credentials to the IAP-protected API backend.

A bit of background: Since Composer is built on top of GCP, your Composer deployment has a unique [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) identity that it's running as. You can add that service account to the IAP access list for your endpoint.

I don't know if the Composer UI makes it easy to see the "email" address for your service account, but if you add the code above and [decode the token](https://jwt.io/) it generates, that will show it.

Comment: "A bit of background: Since Composer is built on top of GCP, your Composer deployment has a unique service account identity that it's running as. You can add that service account to the IAP access list for your endpoint." that's the thing, as I said I did just that and whenever http calls are being made I still get the Google sign in page as a response

Comment: @Vee6 Which service account did you use? It should be the same identity that the Composer environment's GCE instances are using

Comment: it is exactly the same service account. If it is not so I think I will test it with all the available service accounts until it works then figure out which is the real one, otherwise I think something else might be wrong in the setup.